# Play framework 2.3.7 not compiling on intellij 14.1.3

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.3

> Error:Error while importing SBT project:
>
> (...)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: sbt-run-> support-210#sbt-run-support-210_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
>   Invalid response.
>
> See complete log in > /Users/HulkHogan/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea14/sbt.last.log

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

My project is compiling from cli.

I already tried following operations :

- upgrading play from 2.3.7 to 2.3.9
- running "activator idea"
- restarting intellij 14.1.3

Comment: Try downgrading Intellij to lower version. It could be `scala` plugin fault.

Comment: @MonCalamari, instead of downgrading IntelliJ, why not upgrade scala plugin? Play documentation does suggest to upgrade to the latest version of Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [this](http://sakthipriyan.com/2015/04/24/sbt-run-support-210-not-found.html), you need to update your  `project/plugins.sbt` file. replace the version of your sbt plugin with 2.3.6 (is it the latest?)

Answer (score 2):

Deleting .idea/modules and restarting Intellij solved the problem

Comment: I'm using play framework 2.4.4 and sbt plugin 2.4.6 (latest sbt plugin as of now) and removing .idea/modules worked for me. I wonder why though.

By the way @martin-h-works, you should probably update your answer. I think you meant .idea/modules (there's no such folder as .idea_modules).

And also, I didn't have to restart IntelliJ. I just rerun the project, and it was able to compile.